# Jquery mask сбрасывается форма при отправке неполного номера

Tags: jquery, javascript

Форма:

```
<section id="callback_header_js" class="form_holder clear form_holder_js">
   <form id="header_form" action="/include_areas/ajax_sms_form.php" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input required="" class="itext input_mask_js" value="" name="BIG_NUMBER">
   <button class="isubmit" type="submit">Перезвоните</button>
   </form>
</section>
```

Скрипт:

```
   $(".input_mask_js").mask("+7(999)9999999");
$('#callback_header_js').on('submit', '#header_form', function(e) {
    if (!$(".input_mask_js").mask()) return false;

    var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
    var m_data=$(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: m_method,
        url: '/include_areas/ajax_sms_form.php',
        data: m_data,
        success: function(result){
            $('.form_holder_js').addClass('display_none');
            $('.text_result_js').addClass('display_block');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Форма отправляет номер телефона, и вот если номер введен не полностью, форма не отправляется, но почему-то инпут становится пустым.

Как не обнулять поле при неправильно введенном значение, а выводить алерт с ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// неверно (т.к. это повторная инициализация)
if (!$(".input_mask_js").mask()) return false;

// нормально
if (!$(".input_mask_js").val()) return false;

// или
var realValue = $('.input_mask_js').data('mask').getCleanVal();
if (!realValue) return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHXpG/

Answer (score 1):

Добавить вторым параметром `autoclear:false`:

```
$(".input_mask_js").mask("+7(999)9999999", {autoclear: false});
```